# How can I add custom settings for the "Rendered entity" view mode?

Tags: entities

When using the "Rendered entity" field formatter for an entity display, there's a drop-down where you can select the view mode.

Is there a way (programmatically or otherwise) to add settings to a particular view mode? I want to add a checkbox that will display or hide a particular section of the rendered output.

I know I could create another view mode, but that does seem an overkill for something that's otherwise identical.